# Openfiledialog is hung up during showing

Tags: c++, windows, winforms

I have WinForms UI code  in static dll module for my app. Main form has a dialog form, which calls the openfiledialog, when the user needs to change the file path. If I create main winform object in the main thread, than in the new thread call Application::run() all works fine. If I move a main winform object creation in the same thread which will call Application::run(), this works fine for Win XP, but there is hung up for Win7 and Win8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileDialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled is default to true, which means the file dialog would use IFileDialog interface when running on Vista+. The Vista file dialog is based on COM. It needs an STA thread (ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA) as well as a message pump (like Application::Run) to avoid hanging.